# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: python, tkinter, nonetype

I have run into this issue and I can't understand why.

I took my code from my application and made this test code so you don't have to go through a bunch of junk to see what I am asking.

I have this working in other code. But after comparing the two, I can't for the life of me figure this out.

In this application, I get the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete' ".

```
import Tkinter as tk

def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk()
    v = tk.StringVar()
    entryBox = tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v).grid(column=0, row=1)
    def test():
        entryBox.delete(0,20)
    testButton = tk.Button(mainWindow, text='Go!', command=test, padx=10).grid(row=2, column=0) 
    tk.mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this line:

```
entryBox = tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v).grid(column=0, row=1)
```

grid doesn't return anything, so entryBox is `None`, which doesn't have a delete method. You have to set `entryBox` to `tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v)` then call the `grid` method on `entryBox`

Comment: I will vote this up as soon as I build my reputation... That was the fix. Thank you !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you are gridding it in the same variable. If you change your code to the following, it should work:

```
import Tkinter as tk
def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk()
    v = tk.StringVar()
    entryBox = tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v)
    def test():
        entryBox.delete(0,20)
    testButton = tk.Button(mainWindow, text='Go!', command=test, padx=10)
    testButton.grid(row=2, column=0) 
    entryBox.grid(column=0, row=1)
    tk.mainloop()
main()
```

The reason this works is because `grid()` does not return anything.

Comment: This works. Thank you !!!
I will come back and vote this up as soon as i build my reputation :)
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

`entryBox = tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v).grid(column=0, row=1)`

#instead of using in same line you can do like this

`entryBox = tk.Entry(mainWindow, textvariable=v) entryBox.grid(column=0, row=1)`

Answer (score 0):

The `entryBox` that you have declared here has not been obtained yet when you are trying to do call `delete` on that. If you want a simple way to reproduce the error.

```
In [1]: x = None
In [2]: x.delete
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

To fix this you can wrap the entryBox or ensure that it is obtained.

```
if entryBox:
   entryBox.delete(0, 20)
```

Comment: No, that's simply not the problem in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear Entry widget, instead of deleting widget content clear the text variable.

```
text_variable.set("") or v.set("")
```