# Button binding in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, binding

I am using Python 3.5, Tkinter 8.6 on a Windows 7 platform.
For the simple code below, I keep getting the following error message...

```
button2.bind("<Button-1>",PrintAddress)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

CODE

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def PrintName():
    print("My name is ..........")

def PrintAddress(event):
    print("W223 N2257...........")


button1 = Button(root,text = 'Print Name', command=PrintName).grid(row = 0)    
button2 = Button(root,text = 'Print Address').grid(row = 0,column = 2) 
button2.bind("<Button-1>",PrintAddress)    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I guess this has been asked before...The problem is that you create the Button and directly call the grid function on it. grid returns None and this is assigned to your variable. Split the commands.

Comment: Link to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002843/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing:

```
button2 = Button(root,text = 'Print Address').grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Replace it with

```
button2 = Button(root,text = 'Print Address')
button2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

The grid (and pack, and place) function of the Entry object (and of all other widgets) returns None. In python when you do a().b(), the result of the expression is whatever b() returns, therefore Entry(...).grid(...) will return None
-Nick